# Run telerik test case failed with blank IE browser window

Tags: telerik

We test telerik test case on TFS BDT environment.

Telerik runtime has been installed on Environemnt.

Use following command to run test case:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\Test Studio\Bin\ArtOfTest.Runner.exe" test="C:\Test-Code\TestProject1\WebTest.tstest"

The IE opens but blank. And minutes later, test case is failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
following the [post:Configuring Internet Explorer for Test Studio Automation](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/user-guide/configure-your-browser/internet-explorer.aspx) to turn off IE protected mode.

Then test case can run pass.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference in my case.. It still only opens a blank tab and nothing happens, although I have changed the settings of IE